# Django Migratons: What is the best default way to dump and load data in DB apart from using third party app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I'm new to Django and interested in knowing in-depth about migrations so I don't want to use the third-party apps(ex. flyway..)

I want to know how to dump hundreds of data in my Postgres DB without using 3rd party applications.

Comment: Read the in-depth docs on migrations then. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use postgresql tools:

- pg_dump: https://docs.postgresql.fr/13/app-pgdump.html
- pg_restore/psql: https://docs.postgresql.fr/13/app-pgrestore.html

Answer (score 1):

there is a feature called fixtures which you can use:
this is an example of dumping data

django-admin dumpdata [app_label[.ModelName] [app_label[.ModelName] ...]]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried to migrate my database from `db.sqlite3` to `PostgreSQL`.

1. Dump data in the `data.json` file.

   `python manage.py dumpdata > data.json`
2. Edit the `settings.py` file of your project and change the database settings.
   (In my case I have used Heroku's PostgreSQL. You can get all the necessary details from the respective database providers (AWS, Heroku, etc).

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'NAME': ' ', 
'USER':' ', 
'PASSWORD':' ’, 
'HOST':' ',
'PORT':'5432'
}
}
```

3. `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`
4. `python manage.py loaddata data.json`

**If errors are encountered:**

**JSON parsing error:**

Make sure the `data.json` file is saved with `utf-16 LE` encoding (guessed by VS Code).

**Go to:**

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\sitepackages\django\core
serializers\json.py

**Replace:**

```
 stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode()
```

**With:**

```
 stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode('UTF-16')
```